# How do I append a '%' symbol at the end of any value that was put into an input textbox in HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input textbox like this but I want to append % at the end of any value that was input into it at the end

```html
<input type="text" digitsOnly/>
```

So if 50 was put in 50% would display

I tried adding a `::after` with `content: "%"` in the styles but nothing appears at the end of the input. I also tried adding % at the end of my input but it is displaying outside the textbox when I want it to be inside right after the value.

I tried:

```html
<input type="text" digitsOnly/> %
```

Comment: Here you can see that you can't use :after on some input : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-a-before-or-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field

Comment: How did you use ::after in your styles ? Also do you mind using javascript too ?

Comment: Trying to place directly into the input is not great, doing the way you tried is the way to go, you can just render the input & the % to look like one input.   Like how bootstrap does it with input groups -> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/input-group/

Comment: Another idea, a bit like bootstraps input groups, is to give the input a  padding-right, and then absolute position a % symbol inside the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the % next to the input and style the elements to look like a single box:

```css
/* Remove the border on the input */
.box input { border:none; }

.box { border:1px solid grey; padding:1px; }
```

```html
<span class="box">
  <input type="text" digitsOnly/>%
</span>
```

Comment: This works great, but can't you place the cursor ahead of %?

Comment: User Interface really takes a hit with this, eg.  type 10 and press backspace..

Comment: @DreamBold yes, you can and that's a good thing.

Comment: @Keith True, but some key detection could mitigate that.

Comment: what if you put a `%` or move the insertion cursor... you need `/%/g`

Comment: `this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = this.value.length-1;
        this.focus();` Adding this snippet will keep the cursor ahead of %